# Android App is not working on device whereas its working fine on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a android application which is working well on Emulator. But when i tried it on device, its showing some problem like "could not execute method of the activity at" . And below is the logcat report.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3640)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4249)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17764)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.AlarmManager.setExact
        at com.example.manju.remainder.service.task.AlarmTask.run(AlarmTask.java:49)
        at com.example.manju.remainder.service.ScheduleService.setAlarm(ScheduleService.java:50)
        at com.example.manju.remainder.service.ScheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(ScheduleClient.java:55)
        at com.example.manju.remainder.MainActivity.callAlarm(MainActivity.java:507)
        at com.example.manju.remainder.MainActivity.checkDates(MainActivity.java:474)
        at com.example.manju.remainder.MainActivity.submitButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:160)
```

Can anyone help me regarding this..

Comment: are you sure that both the emulator and your testing device are of the same versions?

Comment: ya ofcourse..It is running properly on emulator.

Comment: sorry how to check that!!

Comment: What version of Android is the device? Maybe post the relevant code

Comment: see about device in settings menu and check if both of them run the same version of android.

Comment: Emulator version is 5.1 and My device one is 4.3!

Comment: That's your problem. [`setExact()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)) requires min API 19 and [you have 18](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html)

Comment: Shall i try with set() function ..?

Comment: That would allow it to run but check the docs to make sure it's what you want. Only you know that

Comment: Thank you..! Specially @codeMagic. It is working now..!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   // only for kitkat and newer versions
   android.app.AlarmManager.setExact(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation);
} else {
   android.app.AlarmManager.set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation);
}
```

Basically, `.setExact(...);` method requires API 19 & above (it's just a way to bypass the optimization android provides, for maximizing battery life).

Comment: @ManjuJK Glad it it worked :D, accept it as the correct answer so that others maybe benefited too

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is , set the minSdkVersion in your build.gradle  as the one in your Phone.

Suppose your Phone version is Android 5.0 , then the API Level is 21.  You can set the minSdkVersion 21.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

This will definetly work.